# Question 12, Abstract Algebra: Prove that $\Bbb Z^n_2$ is a group under addition.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic

How would you go about proving the following?

> Let $\mathbb{Z}_2^n = \{(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n): a_i \in \mathbb{Z}_2\}$. Define a binary operation on $\mathbb{Z}_2^n$ by
> $$
> (a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n) + (b_1, b_2, \dots, b_n) 
> = (a_1+b_1, a_2+b_2, \dots, a_n+b_n).
> $$
> Prove that $\mathbb{Z}_2^n$ is a group under this operation. This group is important in algebraic coding theory.

I know that the identity holds, as $a_i + 0 = 0 + a_i = 0$, but I'm not sure how the inverse would hold. If the inverse holds, then wouldn't $a_i + (a_i)^{-1} = 0$?

Additionally, I'm not too sure what the point of the superscript on integers is for. Does it simply mean a series of $0$’s and $1$'s as the elements in it, as $\mathbb{Z}_2 = \{0,1\}$?

Comment: I added the superscript $n$ to the title. You had $\Bbb Z_2$ before, which consists of just the two-element set $\{0,1\}$ along with its operation, whereas $\Bbb Z^n_2$ is like having $n$ copies of that; it is an $n$-tuple of elements each of which belongs to $\Bbb Z_2$. This notation is analogous to writing $\Bbb R^3$ for three-dimensional space, for example.

Comment: Do not use images to convey information not otherwise available in your post. [See here for why it is bad practice](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Given two groups $G,H$, define the direct product $G×H$ in the usual way.  The operation is $$(g_1,h_1)\cdot (g_2,h_2)=(g_1g_2,h_1h_2)$$.  It's straightforward to  check that $G×H$ with this operation defines a group. Just check that the four properties,  inverse,  identity,  closure and associativity are met.

Now an easy induction on $n$ implies $$\Bbb Z_2^n=\underbrace{\Bbb Z_2×\dots ×\Bbb Z_2}_{\text {n-times}}$$ is a group (as $\Bbb Z_2$ is indeed the two element group).

Comment: Ohhh I see. We're showing that since Z2 is a group, then Z2*Z2 is a group no matter how many times we do that operation? Also what about the given binary operation? I wasn't really sure how to use that

Comment: It's the same as the direct product group operation.

Answer (score 1):

For this group, you can find that $(0, 0, \dots, 0)$ is the identity. And the inverse of any element is itself, since they add up to $(0, 0, \dots, 0)$.

The supersrcipt $n$ of $\mathbb{Z}_2^n$ may simply mean the number of 0s and 1s in it.